# Merge elements of array if at least 2 have same property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, filtering, lodash

I have array of objects, that have this structure :

```
days : string // "mo","tu","we"..
time : string // "9am - 3pm"
```

Some times happens when I have 2 (or even more) objects with same `days` value. In this case I need to merge this items (change `time` value, join values from this "same" items)

```js
var array = [{
  days: "mo,tu,we,th",
  time: "9am - 3pm"
}, {
  days: "mo,tu,we,th",
  time: "5pm - 9pm"
}, {
  days: "sa,su",
  time: "9am - 2pm"
}];

var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  var currItem = array[i];
  
  var mergedArray = [];
  array.forEach(function(el) {
    if (currItem.days == el.days) {
      mergedArray.push(el.time);
    }
  });
  var mergedTime =  mergedArray.join(', ');
  currItem.time = mergedTime;
  if (newArr.filter(function(item) {
    return item.days == currItem.days;
  }).length < 1) {
    newArr.push(currItem);
  }
}

console.log(newArr);
```

This is how I can see, how to merge my array items, but I don't like it because of many loops inside. Is there more elegant solution? Maybe using lodash.

Comment: Are you sure you want this? If you join times like that, it seems like those times apply to all the days in the same object, which is not true.

Comment: @trincot, why? I get response from one source in format - grouped days and time (all days in object have this time)... But in case some shop have a break in some days, I get 2 times "time" for that day : If in Monday shop works from 9am to 2pm, then break, and then again work hours from 4pm to 9pm - Response will return me array of 2 objects `[{days:"mo", time:"9am - 2pm"}, {days:"mo", time : "4pm - 9pm"}]`. So I think I'm thinking in correct way, don't I ?

Comment: In that example it is OK, but what if you have multiple days mentioned in the first object's `days` property and combine this with the single-day second object: `[{days:"mo, tu", time:"9am - 2pm"}, {days:"mo", time : "4pm - 9pm"}]`, what will you do? This result would be confusing about Tuesday afternoon: `[{days:"mo, tu", time:"9am - 2pm, 4pm - 9pm"}]`

Comment: @trincot, You are right, but as I know this case is imposible as server returns me correctly grouped days. But I will check it again, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the expected result using [_.uniqWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#uniqWith) and tampering a bit with the object references.

If you don't want to modify the original array, you can pass a [_ .cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#cloneDeep) of the array to the [_.uniqWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#uniqWith) function.

```js
var arr = [{
  days: "mo,tu,we,th",
  time: "9am - 3pm"
}, {
  days: "mo,tu,we,th",
  time: "5pm - 9pm"
}, {
  days: "sa,su",
  time: "9am - 2pm"
}];

console.log(_.uniqWith(arr, function(a, b) {
  if (a.days === b.days) {
    b.time += ', ' + a.time;
    return true;
  }
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Only one method used. Neat! It looks like you don't need that `return true` either, so it's just 3 lines of code :O

Comment: @bfred.it Thanks! Sadly, you do need the return statement in order to remove repeated entries (return false is not needed because undefined is a falsy value and therefore enough to mark the element as not a repetition).

Answer (score 1):

Group the items by days using [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#groupBy), then apply [`_.mergeWith()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#mergeWith) to each group:

```js
var array = [{
  days: "mo,tu,we,th",
  time: "9am - 3pm"
}, {
  days: "mo,tu,we,th",
  time: "5pm - 9pm"
}, {
  days: "sa,su",
  time: "9am - 2pm"
}];

var result = _(array)
  .groupBy('days')
  .map(function(days) {
    return _.mergeWith.apply(_, [{}].concat(days, function(obj, src, key) {
        if (key === 'time' && obj && src) {
          return [obj, src].join(', ');
        }
      }));
  })
  .values()
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

And the prettier ES6 version:

```js
var array = [{
  days: "mo,tu,we,th",
  time: "9am - 3pm"
}, {
  days: "mo,tu,we,th",
  time: "5pm - 9pm"
}, {
  days: "sa,su",
  time: "9am - 2pm"
}];

var result = _(array)
  .groupBy('days')
  .map((days) => _.mergeWith({}, ...days, (obj, src, key) => {
    if (key === 'time' && obj && src) {
      return [obj, src].join(', ');
    }
  }))
  .values()
  .value();

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.16.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have this with 2 loops in javascript without any library:

```js
var array = [{
  days: "mo,tu,we,th",
  time: "9am - 3pm"
}, {
  days: "mo,tu,we,th",
  time: "5pm - 9pm"
}, {
  days: "sa,su",
  time: "9am - 2pm"
}];
tmp = {};
array.forEach(function(item) {
  if (tmp.hasOwnProperty(item.days)) {
    tmp[item.days] = tmp[item.days] + ',' + item.time;
  } else {
    tmp[item.days] = item.time;
  }
});

res = [];
for(var days in tmp) {
  res.push({'days' : days, time: tmp[days]});
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: As `lodash` is already in project, it isn't problem to use this methods. Thats why I wrote about `lodash` in question

Comment: Sometimes the overhead of a library is just not needed (and if someone will search for a solution without the lodash he can use this one) :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this ES6 function, which relies on `Set` and `Map` instances to do its job:

```js
function groupDays(array) {
  return Array.from(
    array.reduce((acc, {days, time}) => 
        acc.set(days, (acc.get(days) || new Set()).add(time)),
        new Map()), 
    ([days, times]) => ({ days, time: [...times].join(', ') })
  );
}

// Sample data
var array = [{
  days: "mo,tu,we,th",
  time: "9am - 3pm"
}, {
  days: "mo,tu,we,th",
  time: "5pm - 9pm"
}, {
  days: "sa,su",
  time: "9am - 2pm"
}];

// group
array = groupDays(array);

// result
console.log(array);
```